# Required Date parameter 'datebegin' is not present SPRING MVC

Tags: hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

try to display the start and end date of a room reservation, and I use SPRIN MVC and JSP. But I have an error message that I am not well understood: "Required Date parameter 'datebegin' is not present"
"Description The request was by the client was syntactically incorrect."

Comment: the message error is:HTTP Status 400 - Required Date parameter 'datebegin' is not present
type Status report
message Required Date parameter 'datebegin' is not present
description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The error stated that `datebegin` parameter was not sent to the controller. Check the calling code. Could be you submit for data without the parameter (e.g. control miss id or the filed is not filled somehow).

Comment: the error description is: "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect."

Comment: t have a over error now with DateTimepichker, the euro is(The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.) and the url is (http://localhost:8080/reservations/reserverroom?roomid=1&datebegin=2016-11-28+09%3A11&dateend=2016-12-07+09%3A12&userid=10)

Comment: Although I have all the files css, js and background for datetimepicker and I set as type:

End date: <div class = "form-group"> <div class = "date-group" id = "book-end"><input
Type = "datetime-local" name = "dateend"

Comment: And I put in my controller DateTimeFormat (pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'THH: mm") Date datebegin, please help me